# Conditional formatting rule to change font colour of only references

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheet in which there are multiple tabs.  In one tab, I want to setup a conditional formatting rule to change the font colour of the entries which are referring to another tab in the same spreadsheet.

My goal is that when the references are replaced with updated data, the colour will be representative of the "new" data versus the estimated data (on the other tab).

In my current attempts, all of the "functions" in the conditional page use the *evaluated* value of the reference, not the reference itself.

Comment: If you are able to, could you perhaps share a copy of your Google Sheet? F.Y.I.: It will show your email address.

Comment: What do you mean by this: "the colour will be representative of the "new" data versus the estimated data"?

Comment: Can't share that sheet specifically.  Might be able to cook-up a simpler one.
Sheet A is being updated with current/new data.  In each of the cells, they show the older data -- stored on the Sheet B.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!  Might not be the most elegant but it is working.

When setting up the conditional-formatting, I selected the cells I needed and chose "Custom Formula" and used:

```
= ISNUMBER(SEARCH("!", FORMULATEXT(C11)) )
```

I believe it works as the `FORUMLATEXT` gets the actual *link* not the data and the (probably not portable) reference to another page always has a `!` in it separating the tab-name from the cell.

The issue I was stuck on was that `SEARCH` raises an error if the thing is not found but returns a number if it is.

So the `ISNUMBER()` wrapper handles the error by returning 0 on the not-found case but 1 when the character is found in the reference text.